# run a Cron job on a daily basis to list out the files

Tags: cron, find

I would like to run a Cron job on a daily basis to list out the files that are being changed on the Test and Production server.

1. The below command will give the list of files whose permission is changed to Read-Write-Execute. If we find any files listed then it is possible that someone not knowing to us are doing it:

   `find $HOME -type d -perm 777`
2. The below command will give the list of files changed in last 2 days:

   `find . -type f -mtime -2 | grep -v "/Maildir/" | grep -v "/logs/"`

Please give me a program that can be setup to be executed on the server on daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the current cronjobs

```
crontab -e
```

Add as last line (this will run every day at 7AM server-side time)

```
0 7 * * * find . -type f -mtime -2 | grep -v "/Maildir/" | grep -v "/logs/"
```

Some nice examples for configuration:

```
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/
```

Answer (score 0):

cron does not accept output on stdout or stderr. This is handled as an error.

Your 'find ..' has to be redirected in a file.

The config of your cron job is shown in the answer from alex.dominte.

Alternative: If you do not depend on a exact point of time you can put your 'find ...'
in a script file and store it in directory '/etc/cron.daily'.
Scripts in this directory are run on a daily basis.